# Point of Inflection or Turning Point?

Tags: calculus

I recently wrote a maths test in school, which by any standards, was exceedingly simple. The last question however, required that we find the value of "t" for which the rate of change of "h" is a minimum given the equation h = f(t) = a(t)^3+b(t)^2+d (I do not recall the exact values of a,b and d as I dont have the question paper with me).

Given the manner in which the question was phrased, I understood that the point of inflection of f(t) was required i.e f ''(t) = 0: solve for t. I calculated accordingly.

When I received my test back, I found that my answer was marked wrong, and that the turning point or local minimum of "h" was required instead i.e f '(t)=0 and f ''(t) > 0. I argued that the answer they required is actually the value of "t" for which "h" is a minimum, and not the rate of change of "h". Am I correct?

(Edit): I now have a copy of the question paper and am able to provide a verbatim quotation of the question:

A tourist travels in a car over a mountainous pass during his trip. The height above sea level of the car, after t minutes is given as:

s(t) = 5t^3 - 65t^2 + 200t + 100

How many minutes after the journey has started will the rate of change of height with respect to time be a minimum?

Comment: Seems to me that there's a bit of a misunderstanding at the "find the value of "t" for which the rate of change of "h" is a minimum" part. If what you said was correct, then yes, your answer should not be marked incorrect. But if the question was asking for the minimum of the original function, then the answer should've been what they've provided.

Comment: I don't think it's so clear. If the rate of change at a point is $-2$, is that a higher or lower rate of change than where it's $0$. Maybe it was meant to be interpreted as the absolute value of the rate of change.

Comment: If the wording of the question was very close to what you report, then we do want where the first derivative reaches a minimum. If the original function is a cubic $at^3+\cdots$, then this will occur at the unique place where the second derivative is $0$. However, in the absence of a verbatim quotation of the problem, one cannot be sure: small differences of wording can substantially change things.

Comment: Please note that a word for word quotation has been provided. Thank you for your help so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rate of change of height with respect to time is $s'(t)$, which is $15t^2-130t+200$. The question clearly asks for the value of $t$ that minimizes $s'(t)$ on the domain $t\ge 0$, so your interpretation is correct. As you say, they minimized $s(t)$, not $s'(t)$.

Note that the question can be answered without doing another differentiation. The graph of $s'(t)=15t^2-130t+200$ is a parabola opening up, so it has a minimum at the vertex of the parabola, which is on the vertical line

$$t=\frac{-(-130)}{2\cdot15}=\frac{13}5\;.$$

Comment: Hi Brian, quick question if you don't mind: given $y=f(x)$, can we say that $f'(x_{0})$ is the rate of change of $y$ with respect to $x$ at the point $x_{0}$? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @TaylorRendon: Yes, that’s right.

Answer (score 0):

More English than maths. If "rate of height changes" was asked for, then you need to consider setting first derivative to zero etc. usual way.